# How to fetch data from Google Sheets and show it on Google Forms?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am making a **Google Form** and I want to add some questions to it, but those questions should be picked **randomly** from a pool of questions which will be in a **Google Sheet**. What needs to be done for this?
For Example: I want to show 5 random questions out the 20 questions pool from the Google Sheets

P.s : I did try already mentioned solution on Stackoverflow but it didn't help for my purpose.

Comment: You should use a webapp instead of a form.

Comment: I added the answer to your additional query to the existing answer .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create a script that answers your issue, I created a sample sheet that looks like this:

[image: Sample sheet]

Where A is the question, and succeeding columns are the options.
Note: You can opt to remove this from the sheet if you only have to generate questions without any options. I included options as that would be the worst case in your issue.

So to start, we need to have the IDs for both form and spreadsheet:

```
var formID = <FORM_ID>;
var ssID = <SPREADSHEET_ID>;
var fData = FormApp.openById(formID);
var wsData = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("Sheet1");
```

Next step is to try and generate questions from spreadsheet:

```
function populateForm() {
  // get all values from spreadsheet
  var ssValues = wsData.getDataRange().getValues();

  // traverse all values
  for(var row = 0; row < ssValues.length; row++){
    var newItem;
    var options = [];
    for(var col = 0; col < ssValues[row].length; col++){
      var cellValue = ssValues[row][col];
      switch(col) {
        case 0:
          // if question, add as item
          newItem = fData.addListItem().setTitle(cellValue).getId(); 
          break;
        default:
          // if not question, add as choice
          options.push(cellValue);
      }
    }
    // add accumulated options as choices for the recently added item
    fData.getItemById(newItem).asListItem().setChoiceValues(options);
  }
}
```

After this step, you should be able to get all the questions added to the form. Now, since we only need to generate 5 **randomized** questions, I've added the function below for us to use.

```
function getFiveRandomQuestions(array){
  // randomly remove questions until 5 remains
  for(var i = array.length - 1; i >= 5; i--){
    array.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length), 1);
  }
  return array;
}
```

The function above accepts an array (the result of `getValues()`) and then remove items from it randomly until only 5 items remain.

Below is the code after integrating all the functions above.
Note: I added `clearForm()` to remove existing items so the form resets whenever I run `populateForm()`. This was for testing just in case you'll need it to. Feel modify the code as much as you need to.

```
// Randomize Form from Sheets
var formID = <FORM_ID>;
var ssID = <SPREADSHEET_ID>;
var fData = FormApp.openById(formID);
var wsData = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("Sheet1");

function clearForm(){
  // clears all items
  var items = fData.getItems();
  while(items.length > 0){
    fData.deleteItem(items.pop());
  }
}

function getFiveRandomQuestions(array){
  // randomly remove questions until 5 remains
  for(var i = array.length - 1; i >= 5; i--){
    array.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length), 1);
  }
  return array;
}

function populateForm() {
  // call clearForm to prevent appending newly randomized questions
  clearForm();

  var ssValues = wsData.getDataRange().getValues();

  // remove random questions until 5 are remaining
  var formItems = getFiveRandomQuestions(ssValues);

  for(var row = 0; row < formItems.length; row++){
    var newItem;
    var options = [];
    for(var col = 0; col < formItems[row].length; col++){
      var cellValue = formItems[row][col];
      switch(col) {
        case 0:
          // if question, add as item
          newItem = fData.addListItem().setTitle(cellValue).getId(); 
          break;
        default:
          // if not question, add as choice
          options.push(cellValue);
      }
    }
    // add accumulated options as choices for the recently added item
    fData.getItemById(newItem).asListItem().setChoiceValues(options);
  }
}
```

Here is the sample output:

[image: Sample output]

Note that this answer is a straightforward one and it can still be optimized based on your test case. Feel free to ask questions if anything is unclear to you.

**EDIT:**

If you want to add hard-coded questions, you need to add it before the loop.

```
// remove random questions until 5 are remaining
var formItems = getFiveRandomQuestions(ssValues);
    
// start of hardcoded questions
fData.addListItem().setTitle('Name').getId(); 
fData.addListItem().setTitle('Email').getId(); 
// end of hardcoded questions    

for(var row = 0; row < formItems.length; row++){
```

Also, if you like to have only five questions and already have 2 via hardcode, we need to reduce the randomizer function to 3 instead of 5.

```
// note that I renamed the function to getRandomQuestions so bear in mind to update the function call too
function getRandomQuestions(array){
  for(var i = array.length - 1; i >= 3; i--){
    array.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length), 1);
  }
  return array;
}
```

Sample output:
[image: hardcode sample]

Comment: Great answer I would say.

Comment: @nazi The solution given by you has worked also I have one query. If I want to have first 2 questions hardcoded like Name, Email and from the third I want to have the questions from spreadsheet what can I do for that? The

Comment: if you need to add hardcoded questions, you need to add them before the loop and adjust the loop from 5 to 3

Comment: @oni3619, i'll update the answer for that

Comment: This really has to be best answer here, detailed explanations and accurately solved your problem

Comment: @NaziA I have found a bug, suppose Person A has submitted a form, and then after sometime Peson B submits the form, the responses of the Person A are cleared but the responses of Person B are there, and this goes on , when Person C submits the response the data for Person B are deleted.

Comment: hi @oni3619, it seems pretty unrelated with the question posted here. The post asks for randomly generating the questions. What this code focuses on is the generation of random questions. Feel free to post a different question as this is out of scope of the original question. Thank you.

Comment: @NightEye Hey, kinda later to the game; I am wondering how can I add the answers to the question (given it is a mc question) and provide an explanation to wrong answers? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For having multiple sections you can also use page break.
In your case it will be

```
fData.addPageBreakItem();
```

This will make a section on new page of the form